# Duplicate Percentage

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server. I have a table like this:

```
+----+-------+-----------+
| Id | Type  |   Value   |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  1 | Phone | 999999001 |
|  1 | SSN   | 333444555 |
|  1 | Phone | 999999002 |
|  2 | Phone | 999999003 |
|  2 | SSN   | 444444444 |
|  2 | Phone | 999999004 |
|  3 | Phone | 999999001 |
|  3 | SSN   | 555555555 |
|  3 | Phone | 999999006 |
|  4 | Phone | 999999001 |
|  4 | SSN   | 555555555 |
|  4 | Phone | 999999006 |
|  4 | Phone | 999999008 |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

...that I need to turn into this:

```
+----+-----------+---------+----------+------------------+
| ID | RelatedID | Matches | Compared | PercetageMatched |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+------------------+
|  1 |         2 |       0 |        3 | 0                |
|  1 |         3 |       1 |        3 | 0.33             |
|  1 |         4 |       1 |        4 | 0.25             |
|  2 |         1 |       0 |        3 | 0                |
|  2 |         3 |       0 |        3 | 0                |
|  2 |         4 |       0 |        4 | 0                |
|  3 |         1 |       1 |        3 | 0.33             |
|  3 |         2 |       0 |        3 | 0                |
|  3 |         4 |       3 |        4 | 0.75             |
|  4 |         1 |       1 |        3 | 0.33             |
|  4 |         2 |       0 |        3 | 0                |
|  4 |         3 |       3 |        4 | 0.75             |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+------------------+
```

Every id grouping would have to compare to every other id grouping and report on their matches.

I cannot find a way to do this simply and efficiently, with the millions of records I have.

My current solution is running a query per record and the query is still going.  Most likely even as you read this.  :)

I even cut the process in half because once one side is evaluated, there side of the equation is the same.

Also, in the end, I am only going to report on anything greater than a certain percentage.  Example > 90%.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is just a thought. Have you considered attacking this from a slightly different direction? What if you pulled together, for each of the values, a list of those values along with how many matches they had. Those with not matches could instantly be thrown out, greatly reducing your set. Then you could work to see what matches existed for those. Seems like attacking things backwards, but what you are trying to produce is not pretty. I came || close to recommending a cursor.

Comment: I like that idea.  So group by count = 0?

Comment: It turns out that 13 million out of the 15 million records have duplicates.

Comment: So for each dupe grab the associated IDs for that group, using a cte, and load it into a temp table. Keep working the patterns down. Ultimately it'll be a really cumbersome query, but keep going down this path I think you'll get there. If I had time this weekend I'd work it up to see what it looked like. Sadly I don't.

Comment: Why would  4 3 compared be 4?

Comment: one set had 4 and one set had 3.  I guess you could say 3 X 4 would be 12 comparisons, and then compare that to how many matches total out of the 12 comparisons.  I was taken the largest count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to find the ids with no matches when you finally filter for a percentage > 0.

Standard SQL based, but fully untested:

```
with cte as
 (
   select Id, Type, Value,
      count(*) over (partition by Id) as RowCount -- maximum number of possible matches
   from tab
 )
select t.ID, cte.Id as RelatedID,
   count(*) as countMatches,
   max(cte.RowCount) as Compared,
   100.0 * count(*) / max(cte.RowCount) as PercetageMatched
from tab as t -- or cte if you need the RowCount, too
join cte
  on t.Type  = cte.Type
 and t.Value = cte.Value
where t.id < cte.id
group by t.ID, cte.Id
```

I don't know about the actuallogic, but you might do the percentage calculation based on the min (or max) of both RowCounts.

Edit:

Of course this will create a huge intermediate result set, mainly based on the count of duplicate values. Following SQL calculates the number of rows before aggregation:

```
select sum(cnt * (cnt-1) / 2), max(cnt), count(*)
from 
 ( select count(*) as cnt
   from tab 
   group by type, value
 ) as dt
```

You might materialize the result of the cte in a table with a clustered index on `(type, value, id)`, maybe this increases performance...

Comment: This was basically what I had already.  The issue I have is it just never finishes.  When I put a top 1000 on the CTE it works.  When I remove the TOP statement it never finishes.  I have 15 million records.  I am starting to think this will not work.  :)

Comment: I am going to mark this as the best answer.  Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.  I think I am going to have to figure out another way to do this.